# Is it possible to use Twitter Bootstrap to create a Magento site?

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap, themes

A client wants a Magento site done, and I have never used it before. I thought, "Sure, I'll create a standard site using Bootstrap and just query the database for the products". Now that I've been looking into it, it looks like the only way to use Magento is by creating a Theme which doesn't look to be Bootstrap friendly.

Please someone tell me that creating Themes isn't the only legitimate way of creating a Magento site.

Comment: Magento is a complete MVC application that depends on the backend logic and application interacting with the front end template system for display. How would Bootstrap begin to understand that? Doing a Google search with the terms: _magento bootstrap theme_ might be a place to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some starting points:

http://www.bootstrapstart.com/portfolio-type/bootstrap-magento-theme/

http://magenthon.com (info and code) or [demo here](http://bootstrapped.magenthon.com)

https://github.com/cvaldemar/magento-bootstrap (doesn't seem too active though ?)

If this is something you are planning on doing yourself, the second link looks like a promising candidate to download, reverse engineer then cusomise!

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I started my own implementation, but I think I'll go with the Magenthon one.

Comment: I was impressed with magenthon as well ... good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate

http://www.webcomm.com.au/blog/2013/09/introducing-magento-boilerplate-a-twitter-bootstrap-3-powered-html5-mobile-first-starter-theme

Newest, Magento 1.8 supported

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Try [this Magento Bootstrap](https://github.com/cvaldemar/magento-bootstrap) framework but it's unstable version.