# How to implement twitter bootstrap in magento theme step by step?

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, magento-1.7

I'm creating a new theme for magento with twitter bootstrap.Can some one help me to do this with bacis step by step procedure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about magneto, but these links may help you. I got these after searching:

1) http://www.redlightblinking.com/magento-tutorials/day-1-creating-a-magento-reponsive-theme-with-twitter-bootstrap

2) [Is it possible to use Twitter Bootstrap to create a Magento site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825717/is-it-possible-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-to-create-a-magento-site)

Thanks.

**Note**: You should try yourself before raising the question, it will help you more.